# How to create a shared static variable for all instantiation of template bass class?

Tags: c++, templates, static-variables

I have a template base class and I would like to create a field call `id` and auto-increment it for any instantiation of derived classes who inherit from this base class. Here is my first attempt.

```
namespace {
    template<class T>
    class BaseClass {
        static uint global_id;
    public:
        uint m_id;
        explicit BaseClass(){
            m_id = global_id++;
        }
    };
    template<class T>
    uint BaseClass<T>::global_id = 0;

    class IntClass: public BaseClass<int> {};
    class DoubleClass: public BaseClass<double> {};

}

TEST(Exp, GlobalIdTest) {
    IntClass a;
    DoubleClass b;
    ASSERT_EQ(a.m_id, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(b.m_id, 1);
}
```

This code, however, creates a separate `global_id` for any translation unit. Is there a way to have a single static global_id for all translation units so the above test would pass?

Comment: All your classes are in an unnamed namespace. The whole point of unnamed namespace is to limit everything inside it to a single translation unit. If that's not what you want, then don't use unnamed namespace here.

Comment: Another thing I see here is that your `global_id` is `private` by default, yet your individual member `m_id` is public. I think you might want to change your class' access modifiers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a single static global_id for all translation units so the above test would pass?

I suppose you can add a `BaseBase` class (struct?) and let all `BaseClass` inherit from it.

```
struct BaseBase
 { static std::size_t  global_id; };

template <typename T>
struct BaseClass : public BaseBase
 {
   std::size_t  m_id;

   BaseClass () : m_id{global_id++}
    { }
 };

std::size_t BaseBase::global_id { 0u };
```

The following is a full compiling (simplified) example

```
#include <iostream>

struct BaseBase
 { static std::size_t  global_id; };

template <typename T>
struct BaseClass : public BaseBase
 {
   std::size_t  m_id;

   BaseClass () : m_id{global_id++}
    { }
 };

std::size_t BaseBase::global_id { 0u };

struct IntClass : public BaseClass<int>
 { };

struct DoubleClass: public BaseClass<double>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   IntClass    a;
   DoubleClass b;
   IntClass    c;

   std::cout << a.m_id << ' ' << b.m_id << ' ' << c.m_id << std::endl;
 }
```